# value from select in textbox json (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, json, drop-down-menu, textbox

I'm using a couple of selects to show a 'startdate' and an 'enddate'. When clicking on the select for year, the month shows, when clicking on month, the date shows and when clicking on the date, the endDate is supposed to append to a textbox. The last I've tried but failed at. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

I'm using the following code:

```
function changeDateType(value) {
    selectedDateType = value;

    $(dateFieldset).hide();
    yearLabel.hide();

    if(typeof(dateTypeCol) == 'undefined'){
        dateTypeRadio.prop('checked', false);
        $(dateFieldset).hide();
        console.log('Selecteer eerst Soort Groep.');
        return;
    } else {
        $(dateFieldset).show();
        console.log('Groepsoort gekozen, geef datumselectie weer..');
    }

    $('.testdiv').attr('data-obj','object');

    yearLabel.show();


    switch(selectedDateType) {
    case 'Weekend':
        $(yearSelect).selectedIndex = 0;
        $(monthSelect).hide();
        $(dateSelect).hide();
        $(endDateText).hide();
        break;
    case 'Midweek':
        $(yearSelect).selectedIndex = 0;
        $(monthSelect).hide();
        $(dateSelect).hide();
        $(endDateText).hide();
        break;
    case 'Week':
        $(yearSelect).selectedIndex = 0;
        $(monthSelect).hide();
        $(dateSelect).hide();
        $(endDateText).hide();
        break
    }

    if(typeof yearCol !== 'undefined') {
        yearCol = '';
        $(yearSelect).empty();

        yearCol = dateTypeCol[value];
        console.log(yearCol);

        $(yearSelect).append('<option value></option>');
        $.each(yearCol, function(key, value) {
            $(yearSelect).append('<option value=' + value + '>' + key + '</option>');
        });
    } else {
        //yearCol = '';
        //$(yearSelect).empty();

        yearCol = dateTypeCol[value];
        console.log(yearCol);

        $(yearSelect).append('<option value></option>');
        $.each(yearCol, function(key, value) {
            $(yearSelect).append('<option value=' + value + '>' + key + '</option>');
        });
    }

}

function getMonths(year) {
    selectedYear = year;
    $(dateSelect).hide();
    $(monthSelect).hide();
    $(monthSelect).show();

    if(typeof monthCol === 'undefined') {
        monthCol = yearCol[year];
        console.log(monthCol);

        $(monthSelect).append('<option value></option>');
        $.each(monthCol, function(key, value) {
            $(monthSelect).append('<option value=' + value + '>' + key + '</option>');
        });
    } else {
        monthCol = '';
        $(monthSelect).empty();

        monthCol = yearCol[year];
        console.log(monthCol);

        $(monthSelect).append('<option value></option>');
        $.each(monthCol, function(key, value) {
            $(monthSelect).append('<option value=' + value + '>' + key + '</option>');
        });
    }
}

function getDates(month) {

    $(dateSelect).hide();
    $(dateSelect).show();

    //console.log(selectedCustomerType, selectedDateType, selectedYear, month);

    if(typeof dateCol === 'undefined') {
        dateCol = monthCol[month];

        $(dateSelect).append('<option value></option>');

        $.each(dateCol, function(key, value){
            $.each(value, function(key, value){
                if(key == 'id') {
                    id = value;
                }
            });
            $.each(value, function(key, value){
                if(key == 'startDate') {
                    startDate = value;
                }
            });
            $.each(value, function(key, value){
                if(key == 'endDate') {
                    endDate = value;
                }
            });
            console.log(id + ' - ' + startDate + ' - ' + endDate);
            $(dateSelect).append('<option value=' + id + '>' + startDate + '</option>');
        });
    } else {
        dateCol = '';
        $(dateSelect).empty();

        $(monthSelect).append('<option value></option>');

        $.each(dateCol, function(key, value){
            id = value.id;
            startDate = value.startDate;
            endDate = value.endDate;

            console.log(id + ' - ' + startDate + ' - ' + endDate);
            $(dateSelect).append('<option value=' + id + '>' + startDate + '</option>');
            $(dateSelect).click(getEndDate(id));
        });
    }
}

function getEndDate() {

    console.log(id);
    $(endDateText).hide();
    $(endDateText).show();

    $(endDateText).val(endDate);

    console.log(id + ' - ' + startDate + ' - ' + endDate);
}
```

Values in last select:

```
reserveren:439 30 - 15-04-2015 - 22-04-2015
reserveren:487 31 - 17-04-2015 - 24-04-2015
reserveren:487 22 - 24-04-2015 - 27-04-2015
```

Value shown in textbox (always picks last loop)

```
reserveren:520 22
reserveren:527 endDate acquired
reserveren:530 22 - 24-04-2015 - 27-04-2015
```

If any other info is required, please ask!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you use all those `$.each` loops? Why not just `id = value.id; startDate = value.startDate; endDate = value.endDate;`?

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I know it's pretty redundant, but i'm new to jQuery and my priority currently is with showing the right info..

Comment: I don't understand the question. Where is the code putting something in a textbox? You're using lots of variables that you never show how you're setting them, like `dateCol` and `endDate`.

Comment: @Barmar Just changed it like you said, didn't know it could be that easy, thanks!

Comment: Never mind, found a solution by getting the dateSelect.val(); and looping through the id's until i found the right one. Thanks for the 'id = value.id;' tip, really helped me alot!